# Transform Non Augmented Reality game into Augmented Reality in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, augmented-reality

I was working on the project of unity 3d but then i started learning AR/VR in unity  so i want to convert some of my projects like roll a ball and paper toss into Augmented Reality so Is there any way to convert any **Non Augmented Reality**  into **Augmented Reality**..?

Comment: What platform are you targeting?  That will be pivotal in converting your projects to AR as you have to target the correct platform and have the correct tools to be installed (ARCore, ARKit, Vuforia, UWP, Meta SDK, Magic Leap SDK, etc).

Comment: Check [AR Camera GYRO (Unity Asset)](http://makaka.org/o/ar-camera-gyro). You can convert your app into AR in 5 min. [AR Camera GYRO — Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD2db.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to Integrate them to Vuforia,ARCore or Arkit.If you integrate your project in Vuforia you can take Android and IOS builds.Arkit is for IOS AR apps and Arcore for Android AR builds.You can make a prefab of all the elements you want in a scene.Drag and drop those prefab into which sample scenes containing SDK(ARcore,Arkit or vuforia)for which you prefer for taking out builds.There are sample examples scenes in those SDKs.Drag them into any scenes and take build.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Onirix](https://www.onirix.com), It's a very easy but also powerful platform to create Augmented Reality experiences, and it provides a Unity SDK.

What you should do with your game is attach the 3D content to any AR anchor (an image marker, surface, etc).